# Is the AzureDevOps/VSTS Spike Icon a Snowflake or a Jack/Knucklebone?

Tags: storyboard, azure-devops, spike

[image: VSTS Spike Icon]

Our team has been arguing over the spike icon in VSTS\AzureDevOps. Some think that it is a snowflake or asterisk. My camp thinks that it is a jack from the childrens game. PLZ HELP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's an asterisk. if you mouse over the icon you can see the tooltip:

[image]